# Visual studio 2015 editor display errors with ECMA Script 6 syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6

I am writing an Application using Node.js webserver. 
I used [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), available since ECMA Script 2015, and my project built correctly.
However Visual Studio 2015 shows me a lot of Errors in its 'Error List' window:
[image: Example]

This is really annoying, does anyone know how to fix this VS2015 behaviour?

Comment: It works in my Visual Studio 15.  Did you make sure its in a proper js block or that it is not the result of some mistake above?

Comment: That's weird... No, if I comment the line, all is OK

Answer (score 2):

Are you just using Visual Studio 2015? Because I am using ReSharper, and you specifically have to set which EcmaScript version you are using.

From the menu bar in VS2015 -> Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> JavaScript-> Inspections -> JavaScript language level.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution soon

Comment: Ok your solution works, but I can't buy a ReSharper license so I'm using 30 Day trial. Do you know another free solution ?

Comment: My bad, in fact it doedn't work. Arrow functions are still considered as Error in the 'Error List' window.